# How to use same JsonProperty Name on two different class

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I use same jsonProperty name on two different classes. Is it possible. 
Please advise on how I can achieve this. Thanks

```
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public RegisteredMailData[] RegisteredMailData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public SendRecieveShipmentData[] SendRecieveShipmentData { get; set; }
```

Edit - Added model for better understanding

```
public partial class MailRoomList
{
    [JsonProperty("GetListItemsResult")]
    public GetListItemsResult GetListItemsResult { get; set; }
}


public partial class GetListItemsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public RegisteredMailData[] RegisteredMailData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public SendRecieveShipmentData[] SendRecieveShipmentData { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("ErrorDetail")]
    public ErrorDetail ErrorDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
}

public class SendRecieveShipmentData
{

    [JsonProperty("__type")]
    public string __type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Address")]
    public object Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Company  Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Doc Type")]
    public object DocType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Line Manager Approva")]
    public string LineManagerApprova { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Material_x0028_Detail_x0029_")]
    public object Material_x0028_Detail_x0029_ { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PKG Type")]
    public object PKGType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Request Category")]
    public object RequestCategory { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sender Address")]
    public string SenderAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sender Company")]
    public object SenderCompany { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sender Name")]
    public string SenderName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sender Phone")]
    public string SenderPhone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Sender Zip Code")]
    public object SenderZipCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shipping Companies")]
    public string ShippingCompanies { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shipping Services")]
    public string ShippingServices { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Telephone")]
    public object Telephone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ZIP Code")]
    public object ZIPCode { get; set; }
}

public partial class RegisteredMailData
{
    [JsonProperty("__type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Collecting Date")]
    public string CollectingDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Created")]
    public string Created { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Designee ين_x0")]
    public string Designeeين_X0 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Mobile phone")]
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Receipent Date")]
    public string ReceipentDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shipping Companies")]
    public string ShippingCompanies { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Tel Number")]
    public string TelNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public object Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you calling *classes* exactly here? Do you want to deserialize `Data` as either of those properties, containing arrays of different custom types?

Comment: Yes, you can use the name json property name in different classes, but it doesn't make sense to use the same json property name in different properties of one particular class.

Comment: RegisteredMailData[] is my class with properties, similar way SendRecieveShipmentData[] is my another class with different properties. When I get response, I get result in Data array.

Comment: You're missing the class definition of ErrorDetail

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be an XY problem that could be solved using generics

```
public partial class MailRoomList<T> {
    [JsonProperty("GetListItemsResult")]
    public GetListItemsResult<T> GetListItemsResult { get; set; }
}

public class GetListItemsResult<T> {
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public T[] Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ErrorDetail")]
    public ErrorDetail ErrorDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
}
```

That way when deserializing you can do

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MailRoomList<RegisteredMailData>>(json);
```

and have access to the desired type array

Comment: Thank you kind sir for guiding me towards generics.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to do it - if you try to serialize a object that has 2 json properties with the same name you'll get a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Demo code, using your model classes:

```
var data = new GetListItemsResult
{
    SendRecieveShipmentData = new SendRecieveShipmentData[]
    {
        new SendRecieveShipmentData
        {
            Name = "foo"
        }
    },

    RegisteredMailData = new RegisteredMailData[]
    {
        new RegisteredMailData
        {
            Status = "ok"
        }
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Exception message:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'Data' already exists on 'ConsoleApp3.GetListItemsResult'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.'

The solution would be to give different property names, for example:

```
public partial class GetListItemsResult
{
    [JsonProperty("MailData")]
    public RegisteredMailData[] RegisteredMailData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ShipmentData")]
    public SendRecieveShipmentData[] SendRecieveShipmentData { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("ErrorDetail")]
    public ErrorDetail ErrorDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir for your efforts, but I dont have control over json and the response is always in Data array.